# Why is function to move canvas object not working

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The objective is to move alien1, atarts from 0,0 then moves all the way to the right, goes down and then all the way to the left, and then down.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def enemigos():
    global Enemigos  #Enemigos downloads the image for alien1
    n = random.randint(1,3)
    
    if n == 1:
        def movalien1():
            alien1 = CanvasJuego.create_image(0,0, anchor = NW, image = Enemigos[0], tags= ('alien1'))
            RIGHT1 = True
            CoordsAlien1 = CanvasJuego.coords(alien1)
            if (CoordsAlien1[0] < 1000 and RIGHT1==True):
                CanvasJuego.coords(alien1, CoordsAlien1[0]+5, CoordsAlien1[1])
                if ((CoordsAlien1[0]+5)==1000):
                    RIGHT1 = False
                    CanvasJuego.coords(alien1, CoordsAlien1[0], CoordsAlien1[1]+50)
            elif (CoordsAlien1[0]>0 and RIGHT1==False):
                CanvasJuego.coords(alien1, CoordsAlien1[0]-5, CoordsAlien1[1])
                if ((CoordsAlien1[0]-5)==0):
                    RIGHT1 = True
                    CanvasJuego.coords(alien1, CoordsAlien1[0], CoordsAlien1[1]+50)
            def rec():
                movalien1()
            root.after(20,rec)
        root.after(20,movalien1())
```

Alien1 does appear at (0,0), but it won't move.

Comment: Have you examined the values inside of `movalien1` to see if they are what you're assuming they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new "alien" every 20 milliseconds. You should be creating `alien1` exactly once outside of `movalien1`. What is happening is that you create it at 0,0, then move it to 5.0. The alien is at 5,0. The next time through the loop you create a *new* alien at 0,0, and then move it to 5,0. You keep creating new aliens over and over and moving the new alien to 5,0.

Also, you can use the `move` method to move an item instead of adjusting its coordinates.

Finally, even though it doesn't actually matter in this code, you are calling `after` incorrectly here: `root.after(20, movealien1())`. It needs to be either `root.after(20, movealien1)` or just directly call `movealien1()` without using `after`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Do I have to make a separate function for the movement of alien1?

Comment: @Chifrijo: no, you don't need a separate function. You just need to move creation of the alien outside of `movalien1`